# Get the fields and values form recordEditForm before submit the form

Tags: lightning, lightning-recordeditform

I am using `lightning:recordEditForm` to generate a form for cloning opportunity record.

currently, there is no functionality to clone a record using `lightning:recordEditForm`.

So what Approach I am using to use the recordEditForm to show all the record values and before submit, I will collect all the field values and create a new Opportunity with Products.

```
<aura:attribute name="sectionFields" type="Object[]"  />
<aura:attribute name="sectionHeader" type="String"  />

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="test"
                              objectApiName="{! v.sObjectName }"
                              recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                              recordTypeId="{! v.recordTypeId }"
                              onsubmit="{!c.onSubmitAction}">
        <lightning:messages />


    <div class="slds-page-header__col-details">
        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider" style="color:rgba(60, 74, 164, 1.0);font-weight:bold;">{!v.sectionHeader}</h3>
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <aura:iteration items="{! v.sectionFields }" var="field">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="12" largeDeviceSize="12" padding="around-small">
                    <div class="custom-box">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{! field.APIName }" class="slds-p-top_small slds-m-top_medium" />
                    </div>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
   <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Save" title="Save"  />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Here sectionFields is list of opportunity fields which is coming from fieldset that I created.

And I am using this functionality to modify all the values that user wants to change. And when user click on submit button it will call `onSubmitAction` method

I am using below approaches to fetch the field data but no success.

```
onSubmitAction: function(component, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault();
        var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
        console.log('-------eventFields-----',eventFields);
        console.log('-------LeadSource-----',eventFields["LeadSource"] );

        var objJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eventFields));
        console.log('-------objJSON-----',objJSON);
        var recUi = event.getParam("recordUi");
        console.log('-------recUi-----',recUi);
    }
```

Any suggestion or solutions.

Also, I found that currently it is in ideaExchange https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKfpQAE but saw few comments about the workaround

[image]

Comment: The Proxy object is still a real object. Your data should be in there?

Comment: yes @sfdcfox but when I tried, the data is not available for me in submit method.